# Am a novice in java Programming and was studing arrays, i stumbled on a code pre-incrementing an array,cant make sence of it

Tags: java, arrays

```
int responses[] = { 1, 2, 6, 4, 8, 5, 9, 7, 8, 10, 1, 6, 3, 8, 6,10, 3, 8, 2, 7, 6, 5, 7, 6, 8, 6, 7, 5, 6, 6, 5, 6, 7, 5, 6,4, 8, 6, 8, 10 };

       int frequency[] = new int[ 11 ]; // array of frequency counters

        // for each answer, select responses element and use that value
        // as frequency index to determine element to increment
        for ( int answer = 0; answer < responses.length; answer++ )
           **++frequency[ responses[ answer ] ];**

        System.out.printf( "%s%10s", "Rating", "Frequency" );

        // output each array element's value
```

Comment: what was your question?

Comment: It wont compile successfully. Check again. Hint : ** **...** **

Comment: @Karna yes, because he didn't understand the increment and thus put an emphasize on the line.

Answer (score 1):

answer is the index of array, response[answer] will give us the value present at that index and then we will increment the value of index (which is response[answer]) in frequency.

```
answer   response[answer]     frequency[response[answer]]    ++frequency[response[answer]]
 0             1             frequency[1]=0                      frequency[1]=1
 1             2             frequency[2]=0                      frequency[2]=1                 
 2             6             frequency[6]=0                      frequency[6]=1
 3             4             frequency[4]=0                      frequency[4]=1
 4             8             frequency[8]=0                      frequency[8]=1
 5             5             frequency[5]=0                      frequency[5]=1
 6             9             frequency[9]=0                      frequency[9]=1
 7             7             frequency[7]=0                      frequency[7]=1
 8             8            **frequency[8]=1**                 **frequency[8]=2**
```

Pseudo code:

Given: Array of response with responses from 1 to 10

Initialize the empty frequency array with default 0 
(frequency[0],frequency[1],frequency[2],frequency[3],.....,frequency[9],frequency[10])

For each value of response array

```
    increment the value of frequency array
```

In the last line, now the frequency of 8 has increased.So In this way it will tell the frequency of each of response.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a loop to display the result:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < responses.length; i++ )
    System.out.printf( "Number of %d: %d\n", i, frequency[i] );
```

Otherwise remove the '*' outside the comments and it will compile.

What it does, is simply use the values of the array as index in order to count them. So when it comes across a '5', the 5th element in the frequency array will be incremented, because there is at least one '5'.

Answer (score 0):

As the value of the operation isn't used, pre-incrementing and post-incrementing gives the same result. So this:

```
++frequency[ responses[ answer ] ];
```

does the same as this:

```
frequency[ responses[ answer ] ]++;
```

which does the same as:

```
frequency[ responses[ answer ] ] = frequency[ responses[ answer ] ] + 1;
```

What the code does is to increment the item in the `frequence` array that corresponds to the item in `responses` array. It simply counts how many there are of each value in the `responses` array.

Answer (score 0):

First : you create `responses` array with `40` value :

```
   int responses[] = { 1, 2, 6, 4, 8, 5, 9, 7, 8, 10, 1, 6, 3, 8, 6,10, 3, 8, 2, 7, 6, 5, 7, 6, 8, 6, 7, 5, 6, 6, 5, 6, 7, 5, 6,4, 8, 6, 8, 10 };
```

Then You create `frequency` with length = `11` ,why 11? because the range of values in `responses` array from `1` to `11` and you want to calculate how many times the number is repeated (ex: number 1 is repeated 2 times , number 6 is repeated 11 times) :

```
   int frequency[] = new int[ 11 ]; // this array with 0 values at each index
```

then , you will loop on the `responses` array

```
for ( int answer = 0; answer < responses.length; answer++ )
```

and `++frequency[ responses[ answer ] ];` which mean that when the index = 1 , you will get `responses [1]` which will equal `2` so you will add `1` to  `frequency[2];` which mean you find number `2` in `responses` and so on

To more understand run this code :

```
 int responses[] = {1, 2, 6, 4, 8, 5, 9, 7, 8, 10, 1, 6, 3, 8, 6, 10, 3, 8, 2, 7, 6, 5, 7, 6, 8, 6, 7, 5, 6, 6, 5, 6, 7, 5, 6, 4, 8, 6, 8, 10};
        int frequency[] = new int[11]; // array of frequency counters

        for (int answer = 0; answer < responses.length; answer++) {
            ++frequency[ responses[ answer]];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < frequency.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(i + "   "  + frequency[i]);

        }
```

The Output is :

```
0    0/////////// mean there is no 0 in responses array
1    2//////////mean you have number 1 in responses array 2 times
2    2
3    2
4    2
5    5
6    11//////// mean you have number 6 in responses array 11 times
7    5
8    7
9    1
10   3
```